# How to append currency symbol as prefix to total sum in views calc?

Tags: 7, views

I have used [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc) module to calculate sum of all column fields. How can I append currency symbol as prefix to **Views Calc** calculated total sum?

Comment: Are you using commerce module ?

Comment: No, I've just created a view and displaying fields total using views calc.

Comment: @venkatesh Which currency symbol you want to append as prefix?

Comment: I need to add $(dollar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that in two ways CSS or jQuery

1)CSS (Note: It requires CSS2 capable browsers. )

```
td.your-views-class-name:before { content: "$"; }
```

2)jQuery

```
$('.your-views-class.name').each(function() {
  $(this).before($('<td>').text("$"));
});
```